Create image carousel using only css
I have created the following code as animation. However, I want it as image carousel, so that after Image 1 leaves the screen then it comes after image 3.
At the moment the animation just starts again.
Any suggestions how to get the carousel effect?
I appreciate your replies!


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AI Image Generator</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .scrolling-images-wrapper {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 220px;
        }

        .scrolling-images {
            display: flex;
            animation: scroll 20s linear infinite;
        }

        .scrolling-images img {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            margin-right: 16px;
        }

        @keyframes scroll {
            0% {
                transform: translateX(0);
            }
            100% {
                transform: translateX(calc(-100px * 5)); /* Number of images to show in one loop * image width */
            }
        }
    </style>

<style>
    @keyframes typing {
        from { width: 0; }
        to { width: 100%; }
    }

    @keyframes progress {
        0% { width: 0; }
        100% { width: 100%; }
    }

    @keyframes robot {
        0% { left: 0; }
        100% { left: calc(100% - 30px); }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body class="bg-gray-100 font-sans">



    <section class="scrolling-images-wrapper">
        <div class="scrolling-images">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Image1" alt="Image1">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Image2" alt="Image2">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Image3" alt="Image3">

        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>




Two copies of the images and move by only 50%.

https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation (no need to copy any images)

Demo of suggestion by @A Haworth.


.scrolling-images-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
}

.scrolling-images {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
}

.scrolling-images img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(calc((200px + 1em) * -3)); /* Number of images to show in one loop * image width */
    }
}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<body class="bg-gray-100 font-sans">

    <section class="scrolling-images-wrapper">
        <div class="scrolling-images">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Image1" alt="Image1">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Image2" alt="Image2">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Image3" alt="Image3">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Image1" alt="Image1">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Image2" alt="Image2">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Image3" alt="Image3">

        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>



